# BLAST+ exits with error exit status (2) when using nextflow

Tags: blast, nextflow

I'm using nextflow to analyse minION data. Blast+ terminates with error exit status (2), Command exit status:2 and Command output: (empty)

```
-HP-Z6-G4-Workstation:~/nextflow_pipelines/nf_pipeline/20221025_insect$ nextflow cat_working_nextflow.nf
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.04.5
Launching `cat_working_nextflow.nf` [admiring_hopper] DSL1 - revision: 2916bc12af
executor >  local (78)
[38/2d0584] process > concatinate (AIG363_pass_barcode01_0eb3c2c3_2.fastq) [100%] 38 of 38 ✔
[dd/3cabdf] process > fastqconvert (output.fastq)                          [100%] 38 of 38 ✔
[47/dab2cd] process > blast_raw (insect.fasta)                             [  0%] 0 of 38
executor >  local (78)
[38/2d0584] process > concatinate (AIG363_pass_barcode01_0eb3c2c3_2.fastq) [100%] 38 of 38 ✔
[dd/3cabdf] process > fastqconvert (output.fastq)                          [100%] 38 of 38 ✔
[47/dab2cd] process > blast_raw (insect.fasta)                             [  2%] 1 of 37, failed: 1
Error executing process > 'blast_raw (insect.fasta)'

Caused by:
  Process `blast_raw (insect.fasta)` terminated with an error exit status (2)

Command executed:

  blastn        -query insect.fasta -db /home/blast/nt_db_20221011/nt     -outfmt 11 -out blastrawreads.asn       -evalue 0.1     -numgnments 1
  blast_formatter blastr-archive blastrawreads.asn awrea-outfmt 5 -out blastrawreads.xml
  blast_formatter       -archive blastrawreads.asn      -outfmt "6 qaccver saccver pident length evalue bitscore stitle" -out blastrawreads_rt.tsv

  sort -n -r -k 6 blastrawreads_unsort.tsv > blastrawreads.tsv

Command exit status:
  2

Command output:
  (empty)

Command error:
  Warning: [blastn] Examining 5 or more matches is recommended
  BLAST Database error: No alias or index file found for nucleotide database [/home/blast/nt_db_20221011/nt] in search path [/home/shaextflow_pipelines/nf_pipeline/20221025_insect/work/96/e885b7e53e1bcf30e33526265e9a3c::]

Work dir:
  /home/nextflow_pipelines/nf_pipeline/20221025_insect/work/96/e885b7e53e1bcf30e33526265e9a3c

Tip: you can try to figure out what's wrong by changing to the process work dir and showing the script file named `.command.sh`
```

The nf file:

```
\#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

//data_location
params.outdir = './results'
params.in = "$PWD/\*.fastq"
dataset = Channel.fromPath(params.in)
params.db =  "/home/blast/nt_db_20221011/nt"

process concatenate {

    tag "$x"
    publishDir "${params.outdir}", mode:'copy'
    
    input:
    path (x) from dataset
    
    output:
    path ("output.fastq") into cat_ch
            
    script:
    """
    cat $x > output.fastq     
    """

}

process fastqconvert  {

    tag "$y"
    publishDir "${params.outdir}", mode:'copy'
    
    input:
    path (y) from cat_ch
    
    output:
    path ("insect.fasta") into convert1_ch,convert2_ch,convert3_ch
            
    script:
    """
    seqtk seq -a $y > insect.fasta
    """

}

process blast_raw  {

    tag "$z"
    publishDir "${params.outdir}", mode:'copy'
    
    input:
    path (z) from convert1_ch
    
    output:
    path ('blastrawreads.xml') into blastrawreads_xml_ch
            
    script:
    """
    blastn \
    -query $z -db ${params.db} \
    -outfmt 11 -out blastrawreads.asn \
    -evalue 0.1 \
    -num_alignments 1 \
    
    blast_formatter \
    -archive blastrawreads.asn \
    -outfmt 5 -out blastrawreads.xml
    blast_formatter \
    -archive blastrawreads.asn \
    -outfmt "6 qaccver saccver pident length evalue bitscore stitle" -out blastrawreads_unsort.tsv
    
    sort -n -r -k 6 blastrawreads_unsort.tsv > blastrawreads.tsv
    """

}
```

I can see that the insect.fasta file has been produced and has the appropriate permissions and is located in the expected dir.

I used the following command to download the nt database

```
update_blastdb.pl --decompress nt --passive --source gcp
```

gcp is the google cloud in Australia

The nt database is ~26GiG in size.

I really need an excel, asn and fasta file from blast results for downstream analysis.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> BLAST Database error: No alias or index file found for nucleotide
> database [/home/blast/nt_db_20221011/nt]

I think you should be able to re-create the above error independently of Nextflow using:

```
blastdbcmd -db /home/blast/nt_db_20221011/nt -info
```

Note that the *db* argument must be a *dbname*, not a path. For `/home/blast/nt_db_20221011/nt` to work correctly, you should be able to list your db files using: `ls  /home/blast/nt_db_20221011/nt.*`

Not sure if there's a typo in your question, but the size of the *nt* database is about an order of magnitude larger, at approximately 250G. I wonder if simply re-downloading the database fixes the problem? Note that you can get a list of BLAST databases (showing their sizes and dates last updated) using:

```
update_blastdb.pl --showall pretty --source gcp
```

Note also that DSL1 is now end-of-life<sup>[1](https://www.nextflow.io/blog/2022/evolution-of-nextflow-runtime.html)</sup> and will be removed going forward. I strongly recommend migrating to using [DSL2](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html) syntax when you get a chance.

---

**From the comments:**

The problem is that when you use *params* to specify a path, the path or files specified will not be localized inside the process working directory when the task is run. What you want is just a second input ([value](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel)) channel. For example, using DSL2 syntax:

```
params.db =  "/home/blast/Geminiviridae_db_20221118/geminiviridae"


process blast_raw  {

    tag { query_fasta }
   
    input:
    path query_fasta
    path db

    output:
    path "geminiviridae.xml"

    """
    blastn \\
        -query "${query_fasta}" \\
        -db "${db}" \\
        -max_target_seqs 10 \\
        -outfmt 5 \\
        -out "geminiviridae.xml"
    """
}

workflow {

    db = file( params.db )

    blast_raw( your_upstream_ch, db)
}
```

Comment: Thank Steve. Using the above command I get this read out
```-HP-Z6-G4-Workstation:~$ /home/blast/ncbi-blast-2.11.0+/bin/ -blastdbcmd -db /home/blast/nt_db_20221011/nt -info
-bash: /home/blast/ncbi-blast-2.11.0+/bin/: Is a directory ```
That wasn't a typo, looks like I've got problems downloading the nt database. I'll see if I can get a copy put on my computer. Once I've done this I'll try again and see how it goes and report back.
I've been teaching myself using the DLS1 version, hoping I can get everything right then switch it over to DSL2.

Comment: @naqs Bash is telling us that the first argument is a directory. I think you may have accidentally included the directory at the beginning of the `blastdbcmd` command when you ran it?

Comment: Hey steve, I haven't added blast to my PATH, so I point the to the folder that has the blast programs in it like -blastdbcmd so bash knows to use this program. Still working on getting a nt db downloaded. In the meantime, I could download a refseq .fasta and use the -makeblastdb command to create a custom db to test out the nf file. What do you think?

Comment: @naqs That could work, but I'd choose the lazy option and just run the download overnight and do the testing in the morning. You could also use the [NCBI FTP site](https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/) to download the individual files from (e.g. `wget ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/nt.00.tar.gz`). With a decent connection, this should take only a couple of hours. Not sure where the space and hyphen are coming from, but the command you want then is: `/home/blast/ncbi-blast-2.11.0+/bin/blastdbcmd -db /home/blast/nt_db_20221011/nt -info`

Comment: thanks @steve. I ran the command above:
```

Comment: @naqs I think the output may not have pasted correctly?

Comment: Hi @steve, my back. I'll try again. Ive downloaded the nt database using the following command
 ```wget https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/nt.*.tar.gz```
This downloaded all the nt .tar.gz files (74 files I think)

Comment: Hi @steve, my back. I'll try again. Ive downloaded the nt database using the following command
 ```wget https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/nt.*.tar.gz```
This downloaded all the nt .tar.gz files (74 files I think)
When I try and extract them using 
```tar -xf nt.00.tar.gz``` or ```tar -xf nt.*.tar.gz``` I get ```gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```
Im assuming the data is corrupt so I will try the with filezilla and change file type from Automatic to Binary

Comment: I havent had time to make a custom db, hopefully tomorrow

Comment: No worries @naqs - they do indeed look corrupt so may need re-downloading somehow. But it looks like there's actually 77 now (as of 2022-11-09). In a new directory, you could try something like: `for i in {00..77}; do wget -c "ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/nt.${i}.tar.gz"; done`. Also, be sure to use the `ftp://` protocol for file transfers. The result is faster downloads compared to using HTTPS. HTH.

Comment: Thanks @Steve - I've copied the command above, I'll run it's running now. I'll let it download over night and then see if i can unzip some of the .tar.gz files in the morning.

Comment: I was also googling solutions to the corrupt files that I downloaded. the thread was saying that instead of downloading ASCII format files, the files should be in binary format. I can do this in FileZilla. I'd be keen to hear your thoughts on this?

Comment: and I'll just show you what's happening as I'm downloading the files:

Comment: Hey @Steve
```nt.00.tar.gz 3%[++  ] 125.44M  46.5KB/s    in 77s     
2022-11-16 19:26:48 (95.2 KB/s) - Control connection closed.
Retrying.
--2022-11-16 19:26:50--  ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/nt.00.tar.gz
  (try: 3) => ‘nt.00.tar.gz’
  Connecting to ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov (ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov)|165.112.9.229|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!```

Comment: continued:
```==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /blast/db ... done.
==> SIZE nt.00.tar.gz ... 4381655025
==> PASV ... done.    ==> REST 131532480 ... done.```

Comment: continued:
```==> RETR nt.00.tar.gz ... done.
Length: 4381655025 (4.1G), 4250122545 (4.0G) remaining (unauthoritative)

nt.00.tar.gz 9%[++=====> ] 407.65M   685KB/s    in 6m 50s ```

Comment: I keep dropping the connection even though my internet is still working. I hope this isnt impacting the data that is being downloaded.

Comment: Hey @Steve, nt.00.tar.gz has finished downloading. I used the following command to unzip the file ```HP-Z6-G4-Workstation:~/blast/nt_db_20221116$ tar -zxvi -f  nt.00.tar.gz
nt.nal
nt.ndb

gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```
I'm assuming this is corrupt as well. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: @naqs Well, ASCII files are just binary files that contain ASCII characters (i.e. text). Usually these can be compressed, and it's almost always better to download and store compressed files. From FTP sites, though, you rarely get a choice of what to download. Often only compressed files are available, especially if they are large.

Comment: @naqs So it looks like your downloads are still failing. If the md5sums (e.g. `wget ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/nt.00.tar.gz.md5`) don't match up, they are corrupt. I'm not sure, but you may be able to just continue again (i.e. `wget -c "ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/nt.00.tar.gz"`) to see if that fixes it? I just tested downloading this file and it does indeed extract using your command above (but you could also just do `tar xf nt.00.tar.gz` and have _tar_ just read the headers and do the right thing).

Comment: Hi @Steve, I followed your suggestions above but with no luck. I have also tried downloading with FileZilla but also no luck. Each time the nt.gz or nt.tar.gz is corrupt.

Comment: so...I created a custom db and have run a file through it and it appears to be working, this was the command

'''
HP-Z6-G4-Workstation:~/blast/geminiviridaedb_20210410$ /home/blast/ncbi-blast-2.11.0+/bin/blastn -db /home/blast/Geminiviridae_db_20221118/geminiviridae -query /home/blast/SLCMV.fna -num_threads 16 -max_target_seqs 10 -outfmt 5 -out geminiviridae.xml 
'''

Comment: I can open the .xml and see blast results. So now, back to the original question about getting the blast process working in the .nf file
I have added this to the .nf file

Comment: `blastn -query $z -db ${params.db} -max_target_seqs 10 -outfmt 5 -out geminiviridae.xml`

Comment: This replaces the command in the original blast script section from above. The error message is below (its long so I've broken it up):

Comment: `
Error executing process > 'blast_raw (sampleID.fasta)'
Caused by:
  Process `blast_raw (sampleID.fasta)` terminated with an error exit status (2)
Command executed:
  blastn -query sampleID.fasta -db /home/blast/Geminiviridae_db_20221118/geminiviridae -max_target_seqs 10 -outfmt 5 -out geminiviridae.xml
`

Comment: `
Command exit status:
  2
Command output:
  (empty)
Command error:
  BLAST Database error: No alias or index file found for nucleotide database [/home/blast/Geminiviridae_db_20221118/geminiviridae] in search path [/home/nextflow_pipelines/nf_pipeline/examples/multi_pipe/work/c7/6d870c4d6e84e5194cd4955a8ab8b5::]
Work dir:
/home/nextflow_pipelines/nf_pipeline/examples/multi_pipe/work/c7/6d870c4d6e84e5194cd4955a8ab8b5
Tip: you can try to figure out what's wrong by changing to the process work dir and showing the script file named `.command.sh`
`

Comment: I'm thinking this is the crucial part:`
`BLAST Database error: No alias or index file found for nucleotide database`

I know the db works without using a container, is the container not recognizing the custom db that I have created?

I am using:
`params.db =  "/home/blast/Geminiviridae_db_20221118/geminiviridae"`

to point to the db

Comment: any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: @naqs Please try to avoid posting command output in the comments. Instead, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74258940/edit) your question to include additional details. Please see my edit above.